# Listing PDFs that contain highlights or comments

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a program that can take a folder path as input and output the list of all PDFs that contain highlights or comments (it should perform a recursive search among subfolders). If possible, free and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.